# Same aside added to the end of multiple answers

Tags: discussion, answers

By chance I noticed that a large bunch of answers by a particular member all end with an almost identical aside which describes the history of the `java.time` package, even though the question does not call for this.

Examples:

- [Windows Time and Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844429/windows-time-and-date-format/54846547#54846547)
- [How to parse datetime with timezone, but no T or nanoseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836037/how-to-parse-datetime-with-timezone-but-no-t-or-nanoseconds/54836873#54836873)
- [ZonedDateTime to Date before Java 8 in early Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828832/zoneddatetime-to-date-before-java-8-in-early-android/54831329#54831329)
- [What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime/32443004#32443004)

Seemingly all of the author's posts on the subject of date/time manipulation in Java, posted across several years, include this virtually identical potted history, and to my eye it doesn't seem necessary or appropriate in answering the actual questions. It also reads a little like an advert for a third-party library which is not related to the questions or the proposed solutions.

Is this something which should be edited out, or is it just a particular writing style which the community considers to be adding something of value?

Comment: It is an answering style.  Nobody knows everything about all subjects, people specialize on a specific topic that interests them.  Given the right kind of question, they don't mind sharing what they know.  It is not obvious why you looked at all of that user's posts, that is not what SO visitors normally do.  I personally prefer to know a little about everything, but it is hard to be consistent.   There are some subjects that nobody seems to know anything about so repeating yourself is kinda necessary to avoid a link-soup post.

Comment: @HansPassant `It is an answering style`: I disagree. It doesn't add anything relevant to the answer, so it's noise, so it should be edited out.

Comment: @HansPassant, I was drawn to look through the user's posts simply because this large aside seemed so out of place that I suspected it might be an advert for a personal software product or library. Looking through the user's profile, and the software library website, I couldn't see an obvious link between the user and the software mentioned, but I did notice that virtually all of their posts included this same large block of text.

Comment: It doesn't just refer java.time, but also Joda time, and the ThreeTen extension library, the latter being open sourced but with commercial support. Can't say whether he's affiliated or just a fan, but unnecessary links to such sites/software generally makes me a bit suspicious.

Comment: It should be an answer to a question like "which java time module should I use?", and then just add a link to that one answer in all his questions. Additionally, the snippet changes over time, as parts of it become obsolete but old answers have the older information. A link to the canonical answer would be superior in that aspect. But I'd let him copy paste whatever he wants if it makes him happy, the rest of the answer is unique and helpful.

Comment: I agree with the idea that it is noise.  When I answer questions about async stuff, I don't go down the rabbit hole and include links to Q, bluebird, and async/await tutorials.  I just answer the question with the relevant info and try to keep the answer as limited as possible.  The only answer that I think benefits from the aside is the last one and the others could just link to it if they wanted.  It's needlessly duplicated otherwise.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

On the one hand, it is interesting information: data that is conceptually appropriate for the question at hand. It's also useful and important if you're going to do date/time stuff with older versions of Java. So it isn't *prima facie* wrong for it to be there.

On the other hand, many of the questions where this text appears are already assuming the use of versions of Java where this library is standard (one of them is even tagged Java 8). As such, the text is meaningless in that context, contributing nothing to the actual answer of the question as posed. That suggests that the copy-and-paste nature of the text is being done blindly to any answer that touches on date/time stuff; it isn't being used specifically for questions where it is appropriate. Essentially, the text doesn't contribute to the answer.

Furthermore, the text is *gigantic*; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54836873/734069) is almost twice as long just because of the copy-and-paste text. Indeed, it is needlessly huge; you could get across the same information in a paragraph. That's not helpful.

Overall, I would say that such text is a net-negative on those answers. Furthermore, I think it would be hard to argue against its removal on the grounds that removing the text changes the nature of the answer, because it really doesn't. The answer doesn't *need* it.

---

[Hans Passant argued in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380536/same-aside-added-to-the-end-of-multiple-answers#comment672773_380536) that:

> It is an answering style. Nobody knows everything about all subjects, people specialize on a specific topic that interests them. Given the right kind of question, they don't mind sharing what they know.

I disagree. The site is trying to build a searchable catalog of problems and their attendant solutions. While it might be interesting to rattle off facts that are related to the subject in question but aren't actually *about* the subject in question, that's not what a good answer does. A good answer provides a solution to the problem as presented.

After all, if I need to use the Java date/time library, odds are good I'm not searching for a specific problem on how that library works. So I will likely never encounter this text. And if I have a problem with making that library do something I need to do... I *already know* how to get access to the library. I have to be using the library in order to fail at getting it to do what I want.

So the only possible way this text is useful is if you're just reading the site, looking for interesting problems that you don't currently have, and just happen across it. And yes, that does happen. But that's not really the most effective use of Stack Overflow, and not one we should optimize for.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR

## It's noise. Edit it out!

Regardless of how "interesting" the appended text is, if it isn't relevant to the question, then it's clutter, and it doesn't belong there. Not to mention that "interesting" is in the eye of the beholder.

I can tell you many an interesting story. These stories are worth telling. Does that make it appropriate for me to mass-paste them in multiple semi-related or unrelated answers? No.

And if I do happen to paste some of my "interesting stories" in answers (which I probably have done over the course of my presence on Stack Overflow), then should the community help lift the quality of my answers by editing out that noise? Most definitely, yes!

Help the OP, help SO. Edit out that clutter.